# Cakephp - detect if unable to connect to database and recover gracefully

Tags: php, database, cakephp, connection

I have a few sites built with Cakephp. If any of these sites lose their connection to the database for whatever reason it does not handle it well. Basically it renders itself inside itself trying to display an error over and over until the browser crashes. The rendering itself inside itself is caused by the use of requestAction from elements.

What I want to know is how can I check if the database connection exists

I tried this in the app_controller before filter:

```
if(!ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default'))
 {
  die(); //this will be a message instead
 }
```

but it does not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
<?php
$filePresent = true;
if (!file_exists(CONFIGS.'database.php')):
  echo '<span class="notice-failure">Database configuration file is not present. Please contact admin@website</span>';
  $filePresent = false;
endif;
if ($filePresent!=false):
  uses('model' . DS . 'connection_manager');
  $db = ConnectionManager::getInstance();
  @$connected = $db->getDataSource('default');
  if (!$connected->isConnected()):
    echo '<p><span class="notice-failure">Not able to connect to the database. Please contact admin@website</span></p>';
  endif;
endif;
?>
```

Here I'm printing messages (in those  tags). You can replace the echo line with die().

Comment: I use this to send me an email if the DB ever goes down! (Im with Amazon RDS), works great! +1

Comment: In earlier versions of cakephp you can use "ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')" to get the db connection.

Answer (score 1):

(Cakephp 3.x) 
Just follow the example given in PagesController's Home view:

Basically it is:

```
    use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

    try {
        $connection = ConnectionManager::get('yourconnection');
        $connected = $connection->connect();
    } catch (Exception $connectionError) {
        //Couldn't connect
    }
    //connected
```

Comment: This works in newer versions of cake 3. But I cannot catch any exceptions, instead cake uses the view "src\Template\Error\missing_connection.ctp" to view the error message...

Comment: Fixed, can catch exceptions using "\Exception" instead of "Exception". See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995594/how-do-i-throw-a-custom-try-catch-exception-on-cakephp