# How do I throw a custom try-catch exception on CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, exception, try-catch, throw

I want to throw a custom exception which is the data validation exception in a controller of my CakePHP application. How do I create my own custom exception handler in Cakephp so that I can throw the exception and catch the exception?

My code example:

```
function getUserDetails($userid){

    try{
         if(!$validUser){
              throw new Exception('Invalid User');
         }

         return $userDetailsData;  //returned from db
    }catch(Exception $e){
         echo 'Error:'.$e->getMessage();
        return;
    }

}
```

is it possible to use here custom Exception class in cakephp so that only those exception can be thrown that what i do. Hope it clarifies question.
thanks.

Comment: have you tried the cookbook? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong on this, but I don't think you should throw exceptions when input data is wrong, that's not the way cakephp works.

Comment: Is this for an api? Please put some example code in the question. Note that [the crud plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud) handles validation exceptions _for api responses_ using exceptions.

Comment: Yes this is for an api and it makes easy and short code for validating data through try catch but i don't want to use Exception class for this because all internal error in server are thrown exception. I just want my own customized exception class so that App's internal error can't be seen to the user. Hope i clarify the question.

Comment: i have updated question with code example. Please suggest.

Comment: The code for your exception handler, or the controller action are what should be in the question. Code (that doesn't work) which throws and then catches an exception doesn't clarify anything.

Answer (score 8):

CakePHP actually depends heavily on namespaces.

Adding `\` to `Exception` should solve your problem.

```
 }catch(\Exception $e){
```

If you want something more, you can create an exception class and get the object from that namespace.

Comment: THANK YOU. That helped me a lot.

Comment: Actually, you should be using use statements at the top, including `use Exception` there also fixes this. Either way, code sniffer with the right ruleset would normalize this code to what I just said, as well.